# Get selected value of select inside table row not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, html-select, getelementbyid

Hello folks of Stackoverflow,
i want to implement a filter for some sort of table in javascript. my text-search does work as expected, but i have some issues with getting an "select" element with js...

Some Code of it:

```js
    function doSomething(){
     var table, tr, td, i;
     
     table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for(i = 0; i < tr.length-1; i++){
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
      
      var e = td.getElementById("ABC");
      
      if(document.getElementById("cb1").checked &&  e.options[0].value == 0){
       tr[i].style.display = "none";
       
      }else{
       tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
     }
    }
```

```html
<label>click me <INPUT type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="doSomething();"></label>
    
    <table id="myTable">
    
    <tr><td>Something</td><td>Some other Thing</td><td><select id="ABC"  name="sel1">
    <option value=0>Default</option>
    <option value=1>Not Default</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tnufmuLu/3/

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Looking at your current code, `e.options[0].value == 0` is always going to be true (once you do the changes suggested by Rahul Gupta).

Comment: I did not specify this: In my original file there is more then 1 table row and the first option (this should be options[0] to my understanding) has a different value assigned to it via php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your code like this

```
function doSomething(){
    var table, tr, td, i;

    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    console.log(tr);
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        var e = td.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        alert('selected value is:' + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
        if(document.getElementById("cb1").checked &&  e.options[0].value == 0){
            tr[i].style.display = "none";

        }else{
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tnufmuLu/25/)
If you want to get the selected value of a dropdown, you could use its  *selectedIndex* attribute.

By the way, we should not define multiple HTML element with same id (please check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp))

Comment: Thanks, i figured out  that i need to assign unique id's to the selects...

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle and created a new [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/tnufmuLu/)

I have corrected some mistakes in your code:

```
for(i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
```

AND

```
var e = document.getElementById("ABC");
```

And also, I have put the javascript code on the top of the HTML code in a `<script>` tag as it was giving `undefined function` error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the for loop mistake was a copy paste error from the original file, where i have more then 1 table entry. and there lies the problem now: in your updated fiddle, e.value has the same value (value of the first tr) all the time, thus rendering this function useless...